# Comparing two time values and storing in an array

Tags: java, android

I have four integers

```
int minute;   int houre;  
int endHour;  int endMin;
```

Suppose first two are `houre = 6 -- minute = 40 so time is 6:40`
Second are `endHour = 22  endMin = 40  so time is 22:40`

Now I want to add 10 minutes and add all possible time values upto 22:40 in an array. Following is the code I am using

```
while (houre <= endHour && minute <= endMin)
            {   
              if (minute + 10 >= 60)
                    houre += 1;

                minute = (minute + 10) % 60;
                Datee dat = new  Datee();
                dat.startHour = houre;
                dat.startMin = minute;
                arrayOfTime.add(dat);
             }
```

The error is at `minute <= endMin` ... it ends at this condition before reaching more hours. Can anyone give me a solution. I dont know why I can't solve this small problem

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule of thumb when working with this kind of situation, Convert the units into a standard unit.

Convert both start and end (hour/min) to min

```
start_min = starthour * 60 + startmin;
end_min = endhour * 60 + endmin; 

while (start_min < end_min) {
  start_min += 10; 
  int hour = start_min / 60;
  int min = star_min % 60;
}
```

Comment: how would i extract hours and minutes?

Comment: int hour = start_min / 60;
int min = star_min % 60;

Answer (score 3):

```
while( !(hour > endHour && minute > endMin) )
```

Your current code continues the while loop until either the hours OR the minutes is greater than the end time. You don't want to exit until BOTH of them are higher than the end time.

That said, Prakash's code is a lot easier to wrap your head around; you should probably go with that.

Actually, a better way to write this might be:

```
while(hour <= endHour || minute <= endMin)
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional should be

```
while(((houre == endHour) && minute <= endMin) || houre < endHour)
```